# Is it possible to install a single submodule from Matplolib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, package

I am using the submodule pyplot from Matplotlib and then packaging my app into an installer. I want to limit the size of this installer, is it possible to install this submodule on its own or a subset of Matplotlib? Currently I'm including the entire Matplotlib library in my installer which seems very excessive and redundant.

Comment: `matplotlib/pyplot.py` [imports](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/690399057f8a26e927cccb33c661c9bac22ae580/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L54-L77) half of Matplotlib. Hard to get rid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Further, pyplot itself includes very large portions of matplotlib within it and I would expect it to be very hard to try to manually extract the portion that you use.